# Prime Number function only printing 2 and 3

Tags: java, primes

```
package PrimeNum;

public class primeNum {
public static void main(String args[]){
    int flag = 0;
    /*
    for(int i = 2; i <= 100; i++){
        if(i % 2 != 0 && i % 3 != 0 && i % 4 != 0 && i % 5 != 0 && 
                i % 6 != 0 &&  i % 7 != 0 && i % 8 != 0 && i % 9 != 0 && i % 10 != 0 ){
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
    */
    System.out.println();

    for(int i = 2; i <= 100; i++){

        for(int j = 2; j <= 10; j++){
            if(i % j != 0) { 
                flag++;
            }
        }

        if(flag == 9 || flag == 8){
            System.out.print(i + " ");
            flag = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

}

The code is made using Java and I can't seem to find why it only prints 2 and 3 all throughout the loop to 100. Any Help please?

Comment: What is your program supposed to be doing?  Why are you checking `flag == 9 || flag == 8` ?  I suspect the problem is that flag is > 9 after 3 and so you never get another output.

Comment: If you don't give us code that is [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) you will get no answer as at the moment your code cannot be compiled by us to check it.

Comment: When the value i is not divisible by the value j it would increment flag to indicate the number of numbers it isn't divisible by. As you would only need the minimum of numbers 2-10 (9 numbers) to divide a number by to see if it is prime, when the program realizes that the number is not divisible by the said numbers then it prints it out. I included 8 for the numbers less than 10. But then, it only prints 2 and 3

Comment: BTW, why you posted commented code here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
package PrimeNum;

    public class primeNum {
    public static void main(String args[]){
        int flag = 0;
        System.out.println();

        for(int i = 2; i <= 100; i++){
            flag = 0;//Initialize flag to 0 here

            for(int j = 2; j <= 10; j++){
                if(i % j != 0) { 
                    flag++;
                }
            }

            if(flag == 9 || flag == 8){
                System.out.print(i + " ");
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Correct way to find prime number

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        int flag = 0;
        for (int i = 2; i <= 100; i++) {
            flag = 0;
            for (int j = 2; j <= i - 1; j++) {
                if (i % j != 0) {
                    flag++;
                }
            }

            if (flag == i - 2) {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Well, it's not so difficult to explain (although I have no clue why you wrote this code, it definitely is no prime test).

In you inner loop, you test if the current number if divisible by the numbers 2 to 10 (you count the number of numbers that do not divide `i`).

For `i=2`, only 2 divides `i`, so after the inner loop, `flag = 8` (`3 .. 10`). Therefore, you print `2` and reset `flag`.

For `i=3`, only 3 divides `i`, so after the inner loop, `flag = 8` (`2` and `4 .. 10`). Therefore, you print `3` and reset `flag`.

For `i=4`, both `2` and `4` divide `i`, so after the inner loop, `flag = 7`. You don't print anything and *don't reset* `flag`.

For `i=5`, only 5 divides `i`. Since you didn't reset `flag`, it will be `flag = 15` after the inner loop. You will never reset `flag` anymore, so you don't print any number any more.

Comment: @downvoter care to explain? OP asks why only 2 and 3 are printed. Well, exactly for this reason.

Comment: The explanation of @Heuster is correct, why the down vote? I voted up.

Answer (score 0):

This may help you

```
 boolean isPrime=true;
    for(int i = 2; i <= 100; i++){
        for(int j=2; j<i; j++){
            if(i%j == 0){
               isPrime=false;
            }
        }
        if(isPrime){
            System.out.print(i+" ");
        }
        isPrime=true;
    }
```

Out put

```
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

Comment: @Aquillo what is your problem??? who use String as boolean here???  better to open your eyes and run this by your own. are you worshiping for boolean???????

Comment: You shouldn't misuse a String when a boolean is clearly the better option here. I'm not going to write any tests for this but this can't be good performancewise.

Comment: @Aquillo this is not deserve to downvote since this is not a wrong answer or mislead some one

Comment: @Aquillo - using a String for informational purposes is actually quite helpful on this one, makes it really clear what's going on in the code - I voted up just for that!

Comment: Yeah use a boolean, also add a break after setting the flag. No reason to keep looping.

Comment: I agree, that using `String` is not appropriate here.
`boolean isPrime` would be better.

Comment: @Aquillo - yes I take your point & I do completely agree in principle, however it was clear in the initial question that the person asking it had no idea what was going on in the code so the String variables literally spelt out what was happening for him quite clearly.. Fair enough I suppose comments in the code might have done the same thing! :-)

Answer (score 0):

What about:

```
public static void main(String args[]){

    System.out.println();

    for(int i = 2; i <= 100; i++){

        int flag = 0;

        for(int j = 2; j <= i; j++){
            if(i % j == 0) {
                flag++;
            }
        }

        if(flag == 1){
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
    }
}
```

Returns:

```
2 3 5 7 11 13 17 19 23 29 31 37 41 43 47 53 59 61 67 71 73 79 83 89 97
```

Answer (score 0):

Your idea of testing every number, counting the numbers that are divisors and printing it when that amount matches the critera is good but I would invert the test a bit.

> a prime number has exactly two positive divisors, 1 and the number itself

If you test every number between 2 and number - 1 you should find exactly 0 divisors. That's true for every number and you don't have to know how many divisors are not divisors and you don't have to test every divisor on every number, 25 can't be divisor for 10 because it is larger.

```
public static void simplePrintPrimesUpTo(int max) {
    // test every number between 2 and max inclusive
    for (int number = 2; number <= max; number++) {
        int foundDivisors = 0;

        // test every divisor between 2 and 1 less than the current number
        for (int divisor = 2; divisor < number; divisor++) {
            if (number % divisor == 0) {
                foundDivisors++;
            }
        }

        if (foundDivisors == 0)
            System.out.print(number + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

This can be optimized further. One interesting property of divisors is

> a divisor of n must be less than or equal to the square root of n

which means that using `divisor <= sqrt(number)` as upper limit in the inner loop would reduce the amount of test required drastically. Calculating the square root of on int is unfortunately ugly but that formula can be squared on both sides and the test gets simpler.

```
(divisor)^2 <= (sqrt(number))^2
```

can be simplified to

```
(divisor)^2 <= number
```

The next optimization that can be done is to skip testing divisors if one was found. It does not matter if there are 2 or 10, it's no prime if we have found one. Result could look like this

```
public static void optimizedPrintPrimesUpTo(int max) {
    nextNumber:
    for (int number = 2; number <= max; number++) {

        for (int divisor = 2; (divisor * divisor) <= number; divisor++) {
            if (number % divisor == 0) {
                // skip testing this number, continue in the outer loop
                continue nextNumber;
            }
        }

        System.out.print(number + " ");
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```